# In uwp when i changes data in c# code it is not updating on front view

Tags: listview, uwp-xaml, auto-update

I am implementing List view in uwp. I bind data to list view  from collection object. when i changes data in collection, it is not updating.Listview remain as it is? Please suggest me what to do to update data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a simple example of what you are trying to do in code (XAML view and C# code to go with it) so that I can help you out in a better way? You question is pretty vague without an example.

Comment: I used  ObservableCollection only instead of list not INotifyPropertyChanged and this resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> when i changes data in collection, it is not updating.Listview remain as it is?

When your property's value is changed, you need to notify the binding clients. So, how to notify?

You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged)
 for your custom class and raises a `PropertyChanged` event when the property is changed.

I've made a simple code sample for your reference:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding tests}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button Content="update" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> tests { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            tests.Add(new Test() { Name="Name "+i});
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var t in tests)
        {
            t.Name = t.Name +" " +DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

public class Test:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!= null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```